# forEach loop doesn't execute as if list was empty despite debug showing 2 elements in the list

Tags: dart, flutter

I got this bit of code executing on a onPressed(). There are 2 elements in the list, they're shown during debugging.

```
print("Got ${myList.length} elements");
myList.forEach((element) => () {
    print('Hello there !!!!');
});
```

I see the "Got 2 elements" in the console. 
However, the debug doesn't go into the loop, and there is nothing more shown in the console.

I am relatively new to Flutter/Dar, and I am stuck, so I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
myList.forEach((element) => () {
print('Hello there !!!!');
});
```

To this:

```
myList.forEach((element) {
print('Hello there !!!!');
});
```

More info here: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Can you please explain the difference ? I haven't yet fully learned all the details of Dart syntax.

Comment: I updated my answer, check the correct implementation

Comment: `=>` means `return`. The first code you are just returning a function, but the second you are actually running it.

Comment: @MichaelYuwono thank you. This was what I hadn't figured out.